# Python, json, which data collection

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create an RSS parser.  I have a list of different sites and their rss feed locations stored in a .json file which I can import and work through fine.

Once the parser has connected to a specific site I want it to grab the the entry titles and links, before then moving onto the next site.  I want it to store this information in a new json file in the following format.

```
{
  "firstsite": {
    "article 1": {
    "link": "https://www.website.com/link1"
  },
    "article 2": {
    "link": "https://www.website.com/link2"
  }
  },
  "secondsite": {
   "article 1": {
    "link": "https://differentsite/link1"
  },
   "article 2": {
    "link": "https://differentsite/link2"
  }
  }
}
```

The goal of which then being i can then iterate over all of the articles/links in 'firstsite'  before going onto those in 'secondsite'.

My question is which data collection should I use?  I thought dict would work, but I don't know if i would need multiple dicts?  I.e. a dict for firstsite, a dict for secondsite, etc....  or is there a way to create a single dict given the above json?  Could somebody give an example please given the above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried it? With a single `dict` I think you'll find that you can only have one `link`, one `article 1`, etc. If your goal is nested objects, use nested dicts (or some other object).

Comment: @hmm No i have not, but thats exactly the same opinion i had.  The other option i thought of was i have three keys in a dict i.e. site: firstsite, article: article1, link:website.com/link1.  I should then be able to iterate via the dict over those sites of 'firstsite', before going to 'secondsite'.  I don't know though if there is a better way?

Comment: `{ "firstsite": { "articles": [ { "title": "article 1", "link": "https://www.website.com/link1", ... } ] }, "secondsite": { ... } }` is perhaps a more clear structure.

Comment: My thought exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this example ... the idea is to have lists of entries embedded as values for your keys. This way, when you parse the json, you can loop through the lists and are always looking up the same key names. If you want, I can make an example of how to walk this structure in Python as well.

```
{
    "sites": [{
            "site_name": "somename",
            "site_articles": [{
                    "article_name": "article 1",
                    "article_link": "https://www.website.com/link1"
                },
                {
                    "article_name": "article 2",
                    "article_link": "https://www.website.com/link2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "site_name": "somename2",
            "site_articles": [{
                    "article_name": "article 1",
                    "article_link": "https://differentsite/link1"
                },
                {
                    "article_name": "article 2",
                    "article_link": "https://differentsite/link2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE: Here's a brief example of parsing the json in Python ...

```
import json 

example = """
{
    "sites": [{
            "site_name": "somename",
            "site_articles": [{
                    "article_name": "article 1",
                    "article_link": "https://www.website.com/link1"
                },
                {
                    "article_name": "article 2",
                    "article_link": "https://www.website.com/link2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "site_name": "somename2",
            "site_articles": [{
                    "article_name": "article 1",
                    "article_link": "https://differentsite/link1"
                },
                {
                    "article_name": "article 2",
                    "article_link": "https://differentsite/link2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""

data = json.loads(example)

for site in data['sites']:
    print(site['site_name'])
    for article in site['site_articles']:
        print(article['article_name'], article['article_link'])


>>>somename
>>>article 1 https://www.website.com/link1
>>>article 2 https://www.website.com/link2
>>>somename2
>>>article 1 https://differentsite/link1
>>>article 2 https://differentsite/link2
```

Comment: That looks great...  If you are happy to add an example of how to walk it that would be fantastic thanks.

Comment: Will do, in about 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks ever so much Matt.  Have a great day.